# Collection Select With Condition in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have two models association looks like :

`User` has_one `Office`

`Office` belongs_to `User`

For Attrubutes looks like :

`User` : id, name

`Office` : id, user_id, address

Scenario for add new an office and select user looks like :

```
<%= f.select :user_id, options_for_select([["Choose User", "0"]] + User.all.collect {|x| [x.name, x.id] if Office.find_by_user_id(x.id).nil? == true }), {}%>
```

If the user have an office, the user doesn't display in select tag.

**Problem :**

I have one user 'A', User 'A' appear on select tag when add new an office.

```
<select id="office_user_id" name="office[user_id]"><option value="0">Choose User</option>
<option value="1">A</option></select>
```

When I add new an office again, **select tag have blank option**.

```
<select id="office_user_id" name="office[user_id]"><option value="0">Choose User</option>
<option></option></select>
```

When I have two user : user 'A' haven't an office and user 'B' too.

```
<select id="office_user_id" name="office[user_id]"><option value="0">Choose User</option>
<option value="1">A</option>
<option value="2">B</option></select>
```

User 'A' have an office and user 'B' haven't

```
<select id="office_user_id" name="office[user_id]"><option value="0">Choose User</option>
<option></option>
<option value="2">B</option></select>
```

User 'B' have an office and user 'A' haven't

```
<select id="office_user_id" name="office[user_id]"><option value="0">Choose User</option>
<option value="1">A</option>
<option></option></select>
```

User 'A' have an office and user 'B' too

```
<select id="office_user_id" name="office[user_id]"><option value="0">Choose User</option>
<option></option>
<option></option></select>
```

etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
users = User.includes(:office)
```

It will fire only two queries.

```
f.select :user_id, options_for_select(users.collect {|x| [x.name, x.id] if x.office.nil?}.compact), prompt: "Please select"
```

Or you can use `join`.